# run batch file in .wav file

Tags: batch-file, wav

Is it posible to run batch file in .wav? I have billing software that wont restart my pc for certain apps, this billing software will play a sound on .wav file before it restart/shutdown the computer. So im thinking that it should be fine if I can put force restart/shutdown if I can place or run batch file on that .wav file.

Comment: You think it's ok for your app to force a shutdown as long as you play a sound? Seriously?

Comment: It is ok to force shutdown/restart if it can be done. It is for cyber cafe use.. There are some online game cant be close by that billing software as i mention. So im trying to find solution to use force shutdown command since it work fine when i try run force shutdown on batch file manually

Answer (score 0):

No, a .wav file cannot run a batch file or any other programs.

Comment: Is there any other way like batch file can be run after .wav file play?

Answer (score 0):

A .WAV file is an audio waveform file which doesn't contain code. You cannot run a .BAT or .CMD file after it executes because there would be no detection system. You could make a Batch file which plays a .WAV file, but not a .WAV file that runs a .BAT file.